# Executing procedure in post deployment script - SSDT

Tags: sql, sql-server, continuous-deployment, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

In my post-deployment script file, I'm executing a stored procedure that is originally created within the db project itself:

**DB Project:**

[image]

But whenever I publish the db project I got the following error

> Procedure st_company_register, Line 56536 INSERT failed because the
>   following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'. Verify
>   that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes
>   on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications
>   and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

The following is the procedure :

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO


    Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[st_company_register]
               @languageID int,
               @company_typeID int,
               @company_name nvarchar(100)
--Untill the end of proc
```

And this is the execution code :

```
 exec [dbo].[st_company_register]
           @languageID =1,
           @company_typeID =4,
           @company_name =N'Company Name'
```

And this is my db project settings which have ANSI_PADDING on:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: "Although the procedure itself has ANSI_PADDING set to ON as following" - Is this option really set? I can see only ANSI_NULLS.

Comment: yeah, correct! let me check this again, but although the ANSI_Padding is marked on the database settings, the procedure isn't created with that option

Comment: 1. Put "SET ANSI_PADDING ON" into your SP. 2. According to "This setting affects only the definition of new columns. After the column is created, SQL Server stores the values based on the setting when the column was created. Existing columns are not affected by a later change to this setting.", I would check current columns ANSI_PADDING settings which used in SP.

Comment: Actually inserting this above the procedure generates a compilation error that this statement is not allowed in this context

Comment: You can place "SET ansi_padding on" in the body of your procedure. It shouldn't generate an error.

Comment: actually it didn't work when I added this inside my procedure, but actually, when I put Set ANSI_PADDING on around the exec statement it worked !, thank you for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this problem while executing a stored procedure **within a post-deployment script**, just wrap the execution statement with **Set ANSI_PADDING ON** as following :

```
Set ANSI_PADDING ON

exec [dbo].[Proc]
           @languageID =1,
           @company_typeID =4,
           @company_name =N'Company Name'

Set ANSI_PADDING OFF
```